# I updated my Anaconda and Jupyter notebook and now the output will not display

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I am a new user. I tried to see if this issue was already posted, but I could not find it.

I was doing data wrangling for a project in Jupyter notebook two days ago. I decided to update my Anaconda platform using the GUI interface. (I am new to coding and am not yet comfortable using the terminal to do things)

For some reason, everything seems fine with my Jupyter notebook except that the output will not show no matter what I do. Even `print()` does nothing.

I have looked around as much as I can elsewhere on the internet. This is not a firewall or security system conflict. Nothing else has changed except the update I did.

I believe my previous Anaconda/Jupyter version dated from March 2018. Is it possible to go back to that version? Would that be the best course of action? What version was current back then? How would I do that? I am on a Mac.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have Anaconda installed on my MacBookPro. Where might I be able to access more detailed info?

Comment: What packages (and which versions) are there in your environment, for example? Does the issue still occur in a new environment?